# Man That's (Really) Fast!

Tags: achievements, dlc-quest

How fast do I need to complete the game(s) to get these two achievements?

[image: screenshot of two achievements named "Man That's Fast!" and "Man That's Really Fast!"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get 'Man That's Fast' you need to complete the **first** campaign in **under 12 minutes**, including getting every secret and coin.

To get 'Man That's Really Fast' you need to complete the **second** campaign in **under 20 minutes**, including all coins and secrets.